# Selectively delete occurrences of a word from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

For example:

```
str = "The quick the brown the fox the jumped the over the lazy the dog."
```

Here, I'd like to know how to do the following two things:

1. Delete only the third "the"
2. Delete *every third* "the"

Comment: You don't count `"The"` as `"the"`, right?

Comment: You don't delete the extra spaces that are left when you delete `"the"`, right?

Comment: @sawa nope the "the" is case insensitive. I was thinking about `.gsub(/the /i, "")` but I don't know how to do it for nth instance. `gsub` replaces all instances of "the".

Comment: Okay, I downvote and closevote because you haven't written so in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP has asked for, the following code:

- doesn't count `"The"` as `"the"`.
- doesn't delete the extra spaces that are left when `"the"` is deleted.

Using this regex:

```
re = /((?:\bthe\b.*?){2})\bthe\b/
```

delete only the third `"the"`:

```
str.sub(re, '\1')
# => "The quick the brown the fox  jumped the over the lazy the dog."
```

delete every third `"the"`:

```
str.gsub(re, '\1')
# => "The quick the brown the fox  jumped the over the lazy  dog."
```